# CMDB Health Dashboard - Custom rule for identification of duplicate CIs

Tags: dashboard, servicenow, cmdb

How can I understand about SNC.MetricProcessorScript.correctnessManager()  deciding for consideration for Duplicates CIs. Is there any way if I can make changes in logic for Duplicate CIs consideration or create any custom rule for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Geneva or newer, you can adjust the duplicate detection by changing the `Identifier` record for the type of Configuration Item you are looking to tweak.

You adjust the `Identifier Entries` to determine how things match and if there is a duplicate entry.

It does this by going in the order of `Priority` and the `Criterion attributes`. Effectively it matches existing Configuration Items with these `Criterion attributes` to determine if it's a duplicate.

You can add a new `Identifier Entry` or disable existing ones.

Also you can add the `Optional condition` field to the `Identifier Entry` form and add criteria to tweak behavior.

This is a great article on this [Duplicate Configuration Items in the ServiceNow CMDB](https://community.servicenow.com/community/blogs/blog/2017/07/26/duplicate-configuration-items-in-the-servicenow-cmdb).

If you can post details on what you are experiencing, someone may be able to help with your specific case.